# Go template won't display slice of structs

Tags: go

I'm fetching data from postgresql using this:

```
type Todo struct {
ID int
Body string
AuthorID int
Done bool
}

err := rows.Scan(&todo.ID, &todo.Body, &todo.AuthorID, &todo.Done)
```

I return this from the function, is a slice of *Todo structs.

In the handler, the output of for

```
_, todo := range todos {
fmt.Fprintf(w, "%d, %s, %d, %t\n", todo.ID, todo.Body, todo.AuthorID, todo.Done)
}
```

is:

2018/10/03 20:09:00 &{1 buy carrots 123 true}

2018/10/03 20:09:00 &{2 cook carrots 123 false}

2018/10/03 20:09:00 &{3 eat carrots 125 false}

the output of

```
fmt.Printf("%#v", todos)
```

is:

[]*models.Todo{}

When I pass this as data to template.execute,

```
<body>

  {{ range . }}
        <div>
            <div>
                <strong>{{ .AuthorID }} wrote:</strong>
            </div>
            <div>{{ .Body }}</div>
        </div>
        {{ end }}
</body>
```

Displays nothing.

I am really puzzled here, there are no errors anywhere, and googling brings me nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I simply forgot to append the new todo insantiation to the todos slice

Sigh, three hours of my life